# ascii value in bash/awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, ascii

i have a doubt, i know that with this command, it prints the value of a character based on the Ascii table:

```
printf "%d\n" "'a" ##prints 97
```

But i wonder how can i make my programm show me the ascii value of a word, can anyone tell me if that's possible, or how do i add up the value of each letter to have the result of the value of the word formed by the sum of the letters?

Comment: The *ascii value of a word* does not exist, only for a character. You could indeed add the ascii values of the characters from that word. But that won't be unique (for example `cat` and `act`). You could also tell us why you want that, so we understand better and maybe we could offer possible alternatives (some form of checksum maybe ?).

Comment: What i have to do is a type of anagram finder, but i need to do it with Ascii values, reading the original word with the anagram of the original, and comparing the ascii value of the original and the value of the anagram, if they're equal, then it most show that the word is indeed the anagram of the original, if they're not equal then ignore that word, i don't know if you get it haha

Comment: Well imagine those "words" (nonexistant, but just for counter-example) : `az` and `by`, they have the same ascii sum but are not anagrams. You need a different approach.

Comment: @FredP, I think the OP's homework is to use such "abstract anagrams" where `az` and `by` would really be considered anagrams.

Comment: @EugenRieck Interesting, that you mention homework, I was suspecting that also... If your answer doesn't fit, I'd suggest sorting the characters before comparing the words... but I won't write a ready-for-use snippet :-\

Comment: @FredP I tend to. If someone takes his homework from here, he is free to do so, as I consider "lazy" to be "good" for a developer. And: One of these days he will need to pass an examen.

Answer (score 1):

If you can abide python, a simple script will display ASCII values of characters:

Create a script (call it for example ascii.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    for c in line:
        print ord(c)
```

then call the script thus:

```
echo "hello" | ascii.py
```

This could easily be modified to total ASCII values.

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to the problem of iterating over the letters of a word, which is not trivial in bash. My approach is horribly hacky, but seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
WORD="$1"
REGEXP='';
ASCIISUM=0
while true; do
        LETTER=$(echo "$WORD" | sed "s/$REGEXP\(.\).*/\1/")
        test "$LETTER" == "$WORD" && break;
        ASCII=$(printf '%d' "'$LETTER")
        echo "Adding '$LETTER': $ASCII"
        ASCIISUM=$(($ASCIISUM+$ASCII))
        REGEXP=".$REGEXP"
done
echo "Sum of ASCII values of '$WORD': $ASCIISUM"
```

Save to e.g. `asciisum.sh` and call with `/path/to/asciisum.sh "word"`

**Edit:**

Some words of explanation:

- REGEXP is used to maintain a regular expression of periods, exactly one for each passing letter - this matches the letters before the one I want.
- Using `sed` I now filter out these already-done letters and every letter after the current one, leaving only the current letter
- If my regexp no longer matches (i.e. WORD is unchanged by `sed`) the loop is broken
- From there it is easy: Calculate ASCII code of letter and add to the sum

Comment: I'm not sure that's what the OP actually needs, from his reply to my comment asking for more information.

Comment: See my comment to your comment ... ;-)